# Jquery | change background color of the table and data if service is stopped

Tags: jquery, html, windows, powershell

I am using script to check list of service is stopped or running using PowerShell. Now I want to change the row color if service is in stopped state.
I am using jQuery to my header file and using function if service is stopped it change the background color. But it is not working. Also I am sending this file over mail body. Please help.

```
$Header = 
 '<style>
 BODY{font-family:Verdana; background-color:lightblue;}
 TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
 TH{font-size:1.3em; border-width: 1px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:#FFCCCC}
 TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:yellow}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  var linhas = $("table tr");
  $(linhas).each(function(){
   var Valor = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").html();
   if(Valor == "Stopped"){
    $(this).find("td").css("background-color","Red");
   }else if(Valor == "Running"){
    $(this).find("td").css("background-color","Green");
   }
  });
 });
</script>
'
```

This is the HTML markup:

```
<tr>
    <th>MachineName</th>
    <th>DisplayName</th>
    <th>ServiceName</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Server1</td>
    <td>World Wide Web Publishing Service</td>
    <td>w3svc</td>
    <td>Running</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Server1</td>
    <td>Windows Update</td>
    <td>wuauserv</td>
    <td>Stopped</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Server1</td>
    <td>McAfee Agent Backwards Compatibility Service</td>
    <td>McAfeeFramework</td>
    <td>Stopped</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Server2</td>
    <td>Task Scheduler</td>
    <td>Schedule</td>
    <td>Running</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Server2</td>
    <td>SplunkForwarder</td>
    <td>SplunkForwarder</td>
    <td>Running</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Server2</td>
    <td>Windows Time</td>
    <td>w32time</td>
    <td>Running</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: *"it is not working"* is not a problem statement. Please read [ask].

Comment: I tested in JSFiddle with both the version of jQuery you are using (doesn't work) and 3.3.1 (does work). See: https://jsfiddle.net/pxvogL7h/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea. Most email clients will not accept javascript. It is best to build the HTML from powershell instead of trying to use javascript.